# Deleting my posts (answers) which is downvoted makes me lose reputation

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers

Sometimes I get downvote with a good comment so I delete my post immediately. And my post is not aged more than one hour. So the downvote let's me loose 2 reputation and when I delete it I loose 2 more reputation.

Can I know why that happened?

Comment: Are you sure that's what is happening? Deleting a post should recover the lost reputation, not the other way around.

Comment: Which answer did you delete? Also are you sure you didn't get a down-vote on another question or answer at around the same time?

Comment: I really can't remember what was it. the problem occurred twice with me. first time was a while ago, second time was yesterday(or the day after for time zone difference). and yes I'm sure - @ChrisF

Comment: Go to your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1567581/mamdouh-alramadan?tab=reputation) > click on `show removed posts` and find out where you get downvote and you deleted the answer.

Comment: @hims056 - it's either this one **PHP cannot modify header, error pointing to code after header** or **Trouble with static properties?** 
not sure though.

Comment: @hims056 - sorry, just found them, this one **End a foreach loop from an if inside** and **What does "?-" mean in Prolog?** those were the two questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These 2x -2 reputation changes were from suggested edits you had to *other* posts which were then deleted:

- [What does "?-" mean in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185144/what-does-mean-in-prolog/14185185#14185185)
- [PHP custom error issue (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221346/php-custom-error-issue-2)

That's intentional, since presumably they were bad edits. I tend to agree the above 2 fit the intention, neither fixes the post.

What's *not* intentional is the delay in recalculating reputation (triggered by those other deletes) or not displaying it.  I'll confer with the team and see what we want to do here.

Comment: @NickCraver Something similar happens to me on occasion, often it is an answer I downvoted that gets deleted and I get my rep back.  However, when it happens my rep occasionally goes down instead of up like it should.  I've assumed that edit deletions do not get immediately recalculated, and it isn't until the deletion triggers the recalc that my rep reflects the actual score (but it is nothing more than an assumption, I've never tried to figure it out in any more detail.